# Avoiding hostile barcode scanner input

Tags: linux, keyboard, barcode-scanner, keyboard-events

We have a kiosk with a barcode reader attached. It's running Linux with Fluxbox.

We've attached our software directly to the barcode reader serial device, but somehow someone manages to kill processes running on the device by sending certain barcodes.

Is there a specific setting that we're forgetting about ?

We have :
kernel.sysrq = 0
in /etc/sysctl.conf

so that should be covered

Comment: How is your barcode scanner recognized by the system? Is it real serial device (`/dev/ttyS*`)? Is it USB device? If it is USB, what is its device class?

Comment: Maybe there is a buffer overflow in your code. Can't tell without seeing it.